# Django Rest-Framework During Validation, Check the Request Method Type

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am working on API Validation Errors to be called. I have to make sure 2 dates don't overlap when making new "POST" calls, which is working fine. I am doing a `model.objects.Filter()` query and if anything gets returned, I return a validation error. However, I want to return this error only during POST requests. I have tried

`if request.method == "POST":`

`do something`

but I get errors under the "request" word saying "request" is not defined. is there another way to check the Method Type during validation? I am doing this in my serializer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass request context to serializer from your view:

```
serializer = SomeSerializer(context={'request':request}, data=request.data)
```

In your serializer, you can access the request method as:

```
self.context['request'].method
```

Comment: Perfect. I used:
if self.contect['request'].method == 'POST':
*do validation*
Thanks alot!

Comment: Cool! If this or any other answer helped you to solve your problem, you may consider accepting it.

Comment: Thanks! I've accepted your answer

Answer (score 1):

Use more than one serializer and redefine `get_serializer_class` a [drf function](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#get_serializer_classself) under your view

```
def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            return PostSerializer
        return OtherMethodsSerializer
```

Comment: I'm sure this works, but I went with kamran890's suggestion first because it was easier to test! and that worked

Answer (score 0):

From kamran890's suggestion, this is what I did on my serializer to do this validation only during a POST method call. Then other types of validation during other calls

```
if self.contect['request'].method == 'POST':
    *do post validation*
else:
    *do patch/put validation*
```

Comment: I will suggest you add this fix in your code, as a part of your question under **EDIT** section. That way @kamran890 can be credited for the answer and future viewers will be able to know the changes you did to your code to fix it. Thanks